# If the date in one field is older than certain date AND two fields match make one of the fields 0

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing payment data. I want to check, if the payment date is older then 9/30/2018 AND if the Balance equals the Charge Amount then set the Balance to 0. I am trying to write-off any balance older than 9/30/2018 if the payment = balance.

The code below seems to be making everything zero if the balance and charge are equal.

```
def MandT(df):
    if datetime.date(df['PaymentDate']) < datetime.date(2018, 9, 30):
        return 0 if df['Balance'] == df['Charge Amount'] else df['Balance']

df['Balance1'] = df.apply(MandT, axis=1)
```

Input

```
Date Svc_From_Amount Charge_Balance1 
8/1/2017 326.00 326.00 
8/1/2017 82.00 100.00 
8/1/2017 82.00 200.00 
10/2/2018 -156.00 -156.00 
12/1/2018 82.00 82.00 
8/1/2017 82.00 -5.00 
8/1/2017 82.00 8.00
```

Expected Output

```
Date Svc_From_Amount Charge_Balance1 
8/1/2017 326.00 0.00 
8/1/2017 82.00 100.00 
8/1/2017 82.00 200.00 
10/2/2018 -156.00 -156.00 
12/1/2018 82.00 0.00 
8/1/2017 -5.00 0.00 
8/1/2017 82.00 8.00
```

Comment: Can you paste snippet of your expected output? you can paste your daframes between ```` (symbol below tilda ~ key)

Comment: Input  
Date Svc From Amount Charge Balance1
8/1/2017 326.00 326.00
8/1/2017 82.00 100.00
8/1/2017 82.00 200.00
10/2/2018 -156.00 -156.00
12/1/2018 82.00 82.00
8/1/2017 82.00 -5.00
8/1/2017 82.00 8.00
  
  
Output  
Date Svc From Amount Charge Balance1
8/1/2017 326.00 0.00
8/1/2017 82.00 100.00
8/1/2017 82.00 200.00
10/2/2018 -156.00 -156.00
12/1/2018 82.00 0.00
8/1/2017 -5.00 0.00
8/1/2017 82.00 8.00

Answer (score 0):

you could use `.loc` to set the value. I assume the `Balance1` is new col you want to add

```
#pop selected row of the balance 1 to 0
df.loc[(df['PaymentDate']) < datetime.date(2018, 9, 30)) & (df['Balance'] == df['Charge Amount']), 'Balance1'] =  0

#pop NaN row of the balance 1 to balance
df.loc[np.isnan(df['Balance1']), 'Balance1'] = df[np.isnan(df['Balance1'])]['Balance']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem may be in

```
if datetime.date(df['PaymentDate']) < datetime.date(2018, 9, 30):
```

As you have not provided more infos about your dataframe, i am assuming that your column "payment date" contain the dates in string format. If i am right, you can try to substitute the code above by:

```
if datetime.datetime.strptime(df['PaymentDate'], "%m/%d/%Y") < datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 30):
```

this code will convert your dates to datetime format making comparison possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try if this works.
You will have to rename the columns appropriately (as you have it in your date) in the code below in all places.

```
df['Date']= pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format='%m/%d/%Y')
def MandT(x):
    if ((x['Date']) < datetime.date(2018, 9, 30)) & (x['Charge_Balance1'] == x['Svc_From_Amount']):
        return 0 
    else:
        return x['Charge_Balance1']

df['Charge_Balance1'] = df.apply(MandT, axis=1)
```